# Display multiple meta_key/meta_values by single SQL query

Tags: post-meta, mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT P.ID, P.post_title, P.post_content, P.post_author,
MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'ex_latitude', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS lat,
MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'ex_longitude', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS lng    

FROM wp_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'post' and P.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY P.ID DESC
```

Result only one post data row

```
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| ID  | post_title | post_content | post_author |    lat    |      lng      |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 10  | Post Title | Post Content |           1 | 56.00078  | 26.45677      |
+-----+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

But how return all posts?

Comment: Are you sure that the query was supposed to return more than one row?

Comment: Yes, have more than 1000 posts with this meta keys

Comment: You could easily achieve the results using a standard `WP_Query` query. Why don't you use it?

Comment: Because I planned to use outside the WordPress.

Comment: So if I understand it properly, you want to get all the posts having the `ex_latitude` or `ex_longitude` metadata, right?

Comment: Not certainly in that way. I want to get all posts along with the metadata and finally encode array to json

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/4kpsKavt).